# Unable to use NoMachineNX to connect to NX server

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, nomachine-nx, nomachine

I have a NoMachineNX server setup with the following status

```
./nxserver --status
NX> 161 Enabled service: nxserver.
NX> 161 Enabled service: nxd.
```

I am unable to connect to this NX server using my NoMachineNX client. The connection request stays at processing state with the message "Waiting for the desktop user to authorize your connection".

I have sudo privileges for the server. I had used the same credentials in the server and at the client.

Answer (score 0):

"Waiting for the desktop user to authorize your connection".

As it says, someone on the server needs to authorize your connection. If it's yourself that's going to be difficult :-) then you should set the server configuration by unchecking the box'Require permission to let users connect'.